# PHP and Apache: hiding php parameters as directories; second parameter not accessed?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I'm currently using the apache code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Categories + Page:
RewriteRule ^([a-z\-]+)/([a-z\-]+)$ /index.php?category=$1&amp;page=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-z\-]+)/([a-z\-]+)/$ /index.php?category=$1&amp;page=$2
# Categories:
RewriteRule ^([a-z\-]+)$ /index.php?category=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-z\-]+)/$ /index.php?category=$1
```

which turns my urls from: 
example.com?category=software&page=mobile 
into
example.com/software/mobile/

Which works fine, and the php file is able to $_GET['category'] fine; however, for some reason, it does not recognize the $_GET['page']; it just results in it being empty every time.

I'm not the best when it comes to Apache code, so would anyone be able to tell me where I went wrong with it?

The code I'm using for php to get the variables is simply:

```
$category = $_GET['category'];
$page = $_GET['page'];
```

Also, if anyone could help me optimize it so that it could work for any number of parameters, that would be even better.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried replacing `&amp;` with `&`?

Comment: you shouldn't be encoding `&` in your rewritten version. it should be just `...&page=$2`.

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't realize that we don't have to encode it.
Still though, for some reason it doesn't appear to be passing any parameters.

Comment: I think you are missing flags. Try `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]+)$ /index.php?category=$1&page=$2 [L]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z\-]+)/([a-z\-]+)$ /index.php?category=$1&page=$2 [PT,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z\-]+)/([a-z\-]+)/$ /index.php?category=$1&page=$2 [PT,L,QSA]
# Categories:
RewriteRule ^([a-z\-]+)$ /index.php?category=$1 [PT,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z\-]+)/$ /index.php?category=$1 [PT,L,QSA]
```

Adding QSA may help

> When the replacement URI contains a query string, the default
>   behavior of RewriteRule is to discard the existing query string, and
>   replace it with the newly generated one. Using the [QSA] flag causes
>   the query strings to be combined.
>
> Consider the following rule:
>
> RewriteRule /pages/(.+) /page.php?page=$1 [QSA]
>
> With the [QSA] flag, a request for /pages/123?one=two will be mapped
>   to /page.php?page=123&one=two. Without the [QSA] flag, that same
>   request will be mapped to /page.php?page=123 - that is, the existing
>   query string will be discarded.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you very much.
I didn't realize that's how Apache's rewrite module works.

It's a bit difficult to get used to, it always looks like jumbled up letters and numbers xD

Thanks again though!
I'd upvote but sadly don't have enough rep yet.